# NetBeans plugin to check for unused CSS/JavaScript selectors?

Tags: javascript, css, netbeans, unused-variables

Is there a NetBeans plugin to check for unused CSS and JavaScript across a project? I know there are tools such as Dust-Me (for Firefox) to do this online for one page, however I am interesting in perhaps a plugin that can look across multiple files and find unused resources.

Thank you!

Comment: I used NetBeans for a Java class, and it underlined un-used variables with a yellow squiggle.  It might be to much work to manually scan your entire code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of any plugin like this written for NetBeans specifically. If you are interested in looking across all the pages in your project, something like [Helium](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) is probably as close as it gets.

While not a plugin for your IDE, you load the JS file into your header so it is present in all pages, and it will scan your site and return a list of unused selectors in loaded stylesheets. Hope this helps!